# What is opencl kernel compiler?

Tags: opencl, llvm

I have a general question. im working on a framework and need to know about the opencl kernel compiler What is opencl kernel compiler? Is there any source for detailed study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the compiler that converts OpenCL kernels to binaries that the platform running them can understand.

For example, if you're running OpenCL on Intel HD graphics with [the Intel OpenCL SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl), that SDK includes a compiler that compiles the kernels down to binaries using that GPU's instruction set.